# Hibernate nested select

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I want from the following query to select only the myEntity (e) results

`String query = "select e, to_char(message_date, 'yyyyMMdd') as dateOnly from myEntity e where e.lang = 'DE' and e.message.messageDate > sysdate-5 order by dateOnly desc, e.message.messageType asc"`

so when I use the following code

```
entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

To get the result as `List<myEntity>` that means to execute the following query

```
select e from (select e, to_char(message_date, 'yyyyMMdd') as dateOnly from myEntity e where e.lang = 'DE' and e.message.messageDate > sysdate-5 order by dateOnly desc, e.message.messageType asc)
```

Comment: It's easier to use the Criteria API of Hibernate if you use Hibernate that is.

Comment: @ambiorix I did use the Criteria Api but then I needed to do the order by `to_char(message_date, 'yyyyMMdd')`, that is to use only the day without take into account the time. My old code was`CriteriaQuery<myEntity> select = cQuery.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(myEntity.class).from(myEntity.class));

Predicate date = ..;
Predicate language = ..;
select.where(date, language);
cQuery.orderBy(b.desc(from.get(myEntity.message).get(message.messageDate)));
cQuery.orderBy(b.asc(from.get(myEntity.message).get(message.messageType)));
List list = em.createQuery(select).getResultList();`

Comment: Possible code solution: use your Criteria, remove the time from the result and order in java.

Functionally: if you have to order on the day, isn't functionally irrelevant that you are also ordering on the time? Because by ordering on time, you are immediately ordering on date too ...

Comment: @ambiorix I want to sort also with the `messageType` field. I didn't mentioned it, but you can see it in the code. That means I want to sort by date and by messageType which is a String. An example of the result would be 
`DATE              TYPE
2013-30-01  10:00   A
2013-30-01  11:00   A
2013-30-01  10:00   Z
`
if I ordeded by date with time  then the 3rd result would be second

Comment: That's true. What error do you now get with the native sql?

Comment: @ambiorix I don't get any error, but the response I get is List<Object> where Object is an array with the first element `myEntity` and the second a `String` that has the value of [to_char(message_date, 'yyyyMMdd') as dateOnly]. I currently run through the results and keep only the myEntity Objects.

Comment: @ambiorix The second returns the error org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: (

Comment: Ah, now I see, it's not native sql, but hql :)
Are you sure the alias in the first query is used? See https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2390?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel

Comment: My problem is solved since I putted the to_char criteria in the order by. That means my query is now 
`String query = "select e from myEntity e where e.lang = 'DE' and e.message.messageDate > sysdate-5 order by to_char(message_date, 'yyyyMMdd') desc, e.message.messageType asc"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved using the following query

```
String query = "select e from myEntity e where e.lang = 'DE' and e.message.messageDate >     sysdate-5 order by to_char(message_date, 'yyyyMMdd') desc, e.message.messageType asc"
```